# Grab Facebook signed_request with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, sinatra

I'm trying to figure out whether or not a user likes our brand page. Based off of that, we want to show either a like button or some 'thank you' text.

I'm working with a sinatra application hosted on heroku.

I tried the code from this thread: [Decoding Facebook's signed request in Ruby/Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987772/decoding-facebooks-signed-request-in-ruby-sinatra)

However, it doesn't seem to grab the signed_request and I can't figure out why.

I have the following methods:

```
get "/tab" do
  @encoded_request = params[:signed_request]
  @json_request = decode_data(@encoded_request)
  @signed_request = Crack::JSON.parse(@json_request)
  erb :index
end

# used by Canvas apps - redirect the POST to be a regular GET
post "/tab" do
  @encoded_request = params[:signed_request]
  @json_request = decode_data(@encoded_request)
  @signed_request = Crack::JSON.parse(@json_request)
  redirect '/tab'
end
```

I also have the helper messages from that thread, as they seem to make sense to me:

```
helpers do
  def base64_url_decode(payload)
    encoded_str = payload.gsub('-','+').gsub('_','/')
    encoded_str += '=' while !(encoded_str.size % 4).zero?
    Base64.decode64(encoded_str)
  end

  def decode_data(signed_request)
    payload = signed_request.split('.')
    data = base64_url_decode(payload)
  end
end
```

However, when I just do

```
@encoded_request = params[:signed_request]
```

and read that out in my view with:

```
<%= @encoded_request %>
```

I get nothing at all.

Shouldn't this return at least something? My app seems to be crashing because well, there's nothing to be decoded.

I can't seem to find a lot of information about this around the internet so I'd be glad if someone could help me out.

Are there better ways to know whether or not a user likes our page? Or, is this the way to go and am I just overlooking something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint should be in your app crashing because there's nothing to decode.

I suspect the parameters get lost when redirecting. Think about it at the HTTP level:

- The client posts to `/tab` with the signed_request in the params.
- The app parses the signed_request and stores the result in instance variables.
- The app redirects to `/tab`, i.e. sends a response with code 302 (or similar) and a `Location` header pointing to `/tab`. This completes the request/response cycle and the instance variables get discarded.
- The client makes a new request: a GET to `/tab`. Because of the way redirects work, this will no longer have the params that were sent with the original POST.
- The app tries to parse the signed_request param but crashes because no such param was sent.

The simplest solution would be to just render the template in response to the POST instead of redirecting.

If you really need to redirect, you need to carefully pass along the signed_request as query parameters in the redirect path. At least that's a solution I've used in the past. There may be simpler ways to solve this, or libraries that handle some of this for you.

Comment: Thanks. That breakdown at the HTTP level was really helpful. I'm rendering the template in the POST now and it works fine; do I need the GET for anything if it's just on Facebook? I might leave it in if people visit the canvas website outside of FB; but FB-wise, do we need it? Thank you so much, this really hurt my head!

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Based on what you're describing, you probably won't need the GET handler. If your app's just a single page, you'll be fine.